# Displaying the window of a background process started by task scheduler in the current login?

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp, scheduled-task, background-process

Is it possible to bring a window that has been started by the task manager in the background to the foreground of an RDP session provided that the same account started the task?

And if so how?

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless the task is started interactively and the account was already logged into the RDP session.  You'd have to use something similar to FireDaemon and have it run in session 0 to be able to switch to that session and see the task window running.

Comment: "TheCleaner" is right about the conditions needed for this to be possible.

Assuming it is an interactive task, that has windows that are hidden, but are in the same logon session you could try bringing it to the front using NirSoft's nircmd (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). The command you want is "win show" I think.

How exactly are you starting the task? Also remotely, or does it run from the local Task Scheduler?

Comment: Runs from the task scheduler

Comment: What about if I just logged into the machine by normal means and no over RDP?  (P.S. it's a VM)

Comment: When you say your remote task starts "in the background", what exactly do you mean? What kind of application is it, is it command-line, simple windowless exe, or does it have windows? If it has windows, it should mean you're running it with some user logged on at the remote computer... but if that was the case, opening an RDP session to that same user would get you what you wanted.

Comment: The application is an MS Access Macro, that is started from a batch file via the command line.  Sometimes it gets stuck and I want to know what the hold up is.  If I can bring the window up I can see what went wrong using the debugger.

Comment: If you can leave that user logged on the server (with an interactive session), then when you RDP (to the same user) that same session should be grabbed and you'll see MS Access...

Comment: It's server 2003.